# accessing an element in a range in D

Tags: struct, d, associative-array

I am writing my first D program, and trying to understand how to implement an associative array. The issue that keeps coming up is that if i create an array like:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.array;

void main(string[] args) { 
   int[string] arr = ["first" : 1, "second" : 2]; 
}
```

everything compiles fine. but if i try and move arr outside of main--into a struct, i get an error saying: Error: non-constant expression.

this throws the error:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.array;

struct foo {
int[string] arr = ["first" : 1, "second" : 2]; 
}

void main(string[] args)
{ /* do stuff with foo */ }
```

I'm sure this is a super simple fix, but this is my first attempt at D.

Comment: I think the issue is that struct sizes are evaluated at compile-time, but the associative array is not allocated until runtime and the compiler has no knowledge about its size etc. Declaring it as `enum` might work. I could be wrong, but I think that's the case. You could try making a constructor as well.

Comment: i tried creating a constructor and got an error that said: default constructor for structs only allowed with @disable and no body. so i just set the array as enum and it seems to be working.

Comment: If you want the AA to be defined at run-time, you'll have to make a constructor that takes in parameters. i.e. struct foo { this(int[string] _a){ this.arr = a; } }

Otherwise, as L33Ts says, use an enum to define it at compile-time. The Compile-Time vs Runtime stuff was the biggest learning curve for me learning D, coming from a Java background at least where you dont really have that. It'll take a bit of getting used to :) !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This limitation comes from the fact that symbols in D modules are not ordered but exist "in parallel". Which is generally a good thing because:

- compiler can possibly do semantic analysis in parallel
- you don't need explicit forward declarations (like in C) to use symbol declared later in the module

With that in mind, consider this code (global scope):

```
int x;
int foo() { return ++x; }
int y1 = foo();
int y2 = foo();
```

If using run-time code was allowed for initializers, values of `y1` and `y2` would depend on order of evaluation which is not defined in general - all globals are "equal".

But for local function variables there is no such problem - they are placed on stack and thus order of evaluation is perfectly defined (it is in lexical order):

```
void foo()
{
    int x;
    int foo() { return ++x; }
    int y1 = foo(); // will always be 1
    int y2 = foo(); // will always be 2
}
```

Because of that compiler restricts you to only compile-time constants when using initializer syntax for globals or struct fields. Constructors (including module constructors) are still OK though:

```
int[int] x;

static this()
{
    x = [ 1 : 1, 2 : 2 ];
}
```

AA literal may look like a proper constant but it actually needs to allocate memory from run-time heap. D is smart enough to accept some of such entities (even some classes) and put them in fixed binary memory section but AA may be extended so proper dynamic heap is necessary.

Also please note that `struct` in D can't have default constructor:

```
struct foo
{
    int[string] arr;
    // this won't work:
    this() { this.arr = ["first" : 1, "second" : 2]; }
}

// need class instead

class boo
{
    int[string] arr;
    // fine:
    this() { this.arr = ["first" : 1, "second" : 2]; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work.

```
struct Foo{
    int[string] arr;
}

void main(){
    Foo foo = Foo(["first" : 1, "second" : 2]);
}
```